# rails scope model without relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rails-activerecord, named-scope, active-relation

I have such model

```
class Ads::Posting < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :child, class_name: 'Ads::Posting', foreign_key: :posting_id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Ads::Posting', foreign_key: :posting_id
end
```

I need to write scope which gets all postings without child. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

that model doesnt make sense!

a children is automatically a parent.

what exactly do you want to make? a tree?

then you need to add to migration

```
t.integer :parent_id, null: false
```

and in your model

```
has_one :child, class_name: 'Ads::Posting', foreign_key: :parent_id
```

for making it deeper, have a look at

```
https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry
```

maybe thats helping you.

Comment: I'm using this for workflow of items. Due to the requirements when user creates posting it should be automatically available on the site (moderator still needs to look through it). When he updates some fields those changes shouldn't be available on the site before morerator approves those changes. Here I use 1-1 relation. And when moderator approves changes I just delete child item and overwrite changes to parent item. If you have better solution for that I'll be glad to hear. I'm not sure that my solution is the best. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using a `LEFT JOIN` and a restriction on the `where` clause.

```
scope :my_scope, 
  joins("LEFT JOIN postings ON postings.ad_id = ads.id").where("postings.id IS NULL")
```